# SSRS: show the Quarter in the chart

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I would like to show in the y-axis the quarter instead of the month:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How can I do this.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
    Select intervaldateMonth as Month, intervaldate as DateValue, intervalDateWeek as Datum,

SUM(GoodUnits) As GoodUnits,
SUM(TheoreticalUnits) As TheoreticalUnits,


from Count inner join tsystem ON Count.systemid = tsystem.id
    where IntervalDateMonth >=getdate()-420
AND ((DATEPART(dw, IntervalDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0,1)
    and tsystem.ID in  (Select SystemID from tSystemViewSystem where SystemViewID = 2)                          
    group by intervaldatemonth, intervaldate, intervaldateweek
    ) as s
```

Comment: I'd suggest case when intervaldateMonth between 1 and 3 then 1 else case when intervaldateMonth between 4 and 6 then 1 else case ..... same in the group by or rap it by another select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the quarter of the date you can use this expression in Category Groups:

```
="Q" & DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,Fields!DateValue.Value)
```

**UPDATE**:

Go to Category Groups properties:

[image]

And use the expression in `Label` and `Group on` properties.

[image]

You will get something like this:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: What do you get when using this expression?

Comment: Why my answer have been down voted if it solved the OP question and It was accepted?